# How to Store Boost Factor of Field in Index in lucene

Tags: c#, lucene.net

I am using lucene to search in the address book like product. I want to boost the search results according to some specific criteria. (e.g. Match in location field should have greater relevance than match in name of entity.) This is fixed criteria for my case.

I am trying to store the boostfactor with Field by calling SetBoost() method while indexing. But then also result's score is not as expected. It's considering same boost value for every field.

Can anybody suggest me where I am going wrong?

Code I am using to build the index.

```
Directory objIndexDirectory =
  FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(<PathOfIndexFolder>));
StandardAnalyzer objAnalyzer =
  new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29);
IndexWriter objWriter = new IndexWriter(
  objIndexDirectory, objAnalyzer, true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
Document objDocument = new Document();
Field objName =
  new Field("Name", "John Doe", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
Field objLocation =
  new Field("Location", "NY", Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
objLocation.SetBoost((2f);
objDocument.Add(objName);
objDocument.Add(objLocation);
objWriter.AddDocument(objDocument);
```

What I am trying to achieve is,
Assuming there is three entries in index:

1. John Doe, NY
2. John Foo, New Jercy
3. XYZ, NY

In this case if the search query is "John NY", then result should have relevance like

1. John Doe, NY
2. XYZ, NY
3. John Foo, New Jercy

Comment: Can you add some code that shows how you are building your index?

Comment: Hi goalie! I've added the code and my expected scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't figure out what you think is wrong with your approach, but here is the code I was using to test with:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RAMDirectory dir = new RAMDirectory();

        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(dir, new StandardAnalyzer());

        AddDocument(writer, "John Doe", "NY");
        AddDocument(writer, "John Foo", "New Jersey");
        AddDocument(writer, "XYZ", "NY");

        writer.Commit();

        BooleanQuery query = new BooleanQuery();
        query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Name", "john")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
        query.Add(new TermQuery(new Term("Location", "NY")), BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);

        IndexReader reader = writer.GetReader();

        IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(reader);
        var hits = searcher.Search(query, null, 10);

        for (int i = 0; i < hits.totalHits; i++)
        {
            Document doc = searcher.Doc(hits.scoreDocs[i].doc);
            var explain = searcher.Explain(query, hits.scoreDocs[i].doc);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} - {1} - {2}", hits.scoreDocs[i].score, doc.ToString(), explain.ToString());
        }
    }

    private static void AddDocument(IndexWriter writer, string name, string address)
    {
        Document objDocument = new Document();
        Field objName = new Field("Name", name, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED);
        Field objLocation = new Field("Location", address, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED);
        objLocation.SetBoost(2f);
        objDocument.Add(objName);
        objDocument.Add(objLocation);
        writer.AddDocument(objDocument);
    }
}
```

This code does return the results in the order you wish.  In fact it returns them in that order for this set if you exclude the boost.  I'm not an expert on Lucene scoring, but I believe this is because you are matching "NY" exactly for "XYZ, NY", and the "John" query is a partial match.  You can read the details printed out via the Explain class.

Comment: Hi goalie! I've tried your code. I found out where I am going wrong. I am Querying like this. "QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("Name", objAnalyzer); Query query = parser.Parse("John NY"); Searcher objSearcher = new IndexSearcher(<IndexDirPath>); Hits objHits = objSearcher.Search(query);" Means, I am searching on 'Name' Field only, so it's not considering boost factor of 'Location' Field. But the problem is, User will enter Search Query like 'John NY' only, in which I won't be able to extract that 'John' is Name and 'NY' is Location. So is there any way to query without specifying field?

Comment: That might be difficult.  Is it possible to provide 2 inputs for the user?  You might try splitting on a space and doing a WildCard query on each field for all the tokens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried MultiFieldQueryParser?